# C# отсканированного файла

Tags: c#, исключения

В коде из сервера получаю сканированную картинку и из него получаю массив байтов и картинка должен сохраняться в БД. Вот код для сохранения`

```
  try
        { 
            UploadFileMaintenance upl = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();
            PX.SM.FileInfo fileinfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(@"ShipmentEntry\", null, arr);
            if (upl.SaveFile(fileinfo, FileExistsAction.CreateVersion))
            {
                if (fileinfo.UID.HasValue)
                {
                    PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(this.Base.Caches["SOShipment"], (SOShipment)(this.Base.Caches["SOShipment"].Current), fileinfo.UID.Value);
                    this.Base.Save.Press();
                }  
            }
        }
        catch (PXException ex)
        {
            ///
        }
```

на этом строке `if (upl.SaveFile(fileinfo, FileExistsAction.CreateVersion))` получаю вот такое исключение **File type is not allowed**. Код работает в системе `AcuamticaERP`

Comment: upl.SaveFile(...) - это что? там и нужно искать ошибку.

Comment: Вроде бы достаточно понятное исключение. Тип файла не поддерживается. К примеру туда можно добавить `.jpg`, а Вы туда `.pdf` засовываете.

Comment: в любом случае воспроизвести эту ошибку ни у кого кроме вас не получится, все использованные в приведенном примере кода классы самописные, даже вроде бы привычный FileInfo (нет у стандартного такого конструктора). Так что либо вы приведете воспроизводимый пример вашей проблемы, либо будем гадать: вы на чем предпочитаете? я на хрустальном шаре например.

Comment: @rdorn  этот код написан я системе `Acumatica` так что не стандартные функции для `C#` это все в  фреймворке  `Acumatica`

Comment: @DenisBubnov  а как массив байтов  конвертировать в файл `.jpg`?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan в вопрос добавьте информацию о фреймворке, может и найдется кто-то, кто знает что это такое. Фреймворков разных сейчас что блох на собаке.

Comment: Это я Вам как пример привел. Если дословно перевести текст исключения, то получится: *Тип файла не допускается*. Поэтому в Вашем случае только гадать, если не приведете воспроизводимый пример вашей проблемы.

Comment: @VardanVardanyan судя по выдаче гугла `Acumatica` - коммерческий фреймворк, так что это скорее вопрос в техподдержку, или на EnSO можно поинтересоваться, может там найдется один из авторов этого фреймворка, он вроде как не отечественный. Только не забудьте указать его название в вопросе.

Comment: заголовок вопроса звучит, как диагноз

Comment: Я в документации к Вашей системе наткнулся на интересное замечание, что разрешение файлов нужно регистрировать если Вы хотите сделать Upload в систему. У Вас это сделано?
"Image file extensions of files to be uploaded must be registered on the File Upload Preferences (SM.20.25.50) form. Navigate to the Сonfiguration > Document Management > Configure > File Upload Preferences form. If the required file types are not defined already, define them and save your changes. On this form, you can also define the maximum size of an uploaded file (in kilobytes), as shown in the  following screenshot."

Comment: спасибо всем ,проблема решена всё дело было в передаче массив байтов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что у Вас неправильно инициализирован  fileinfo и у Вас нет самого имени файла и его разрешения. Скорее всего причина исключения в этой строке:

```
           PX.SM.FileInfo fileinfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(@"ShipmentEntry\", null, arr);
```

Я тут у Ваших коллег нашел вот это:

```
  PX.SM.FileInfo fileinfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo("case.pdf", null, data);
```

Comment: да уже нашёл  спасибо за отзыв вот мой вариант `PX.SM.FileInfo fileinfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(@"SOShipmentEntry\Image_"+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"_"+DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()+".png", null, arr);`  здесь скорее важно задать не имя файлу а тип в моём случаи `.png`